# Parsing a binary file with multiple data types into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, split, binary

I've created multiple binary files, each containing 2 strings, 2 chars, 1 double, and 1 int. The data, when read, is

```
Fokker DR 1 
Germany 
D 
A 
1000.0 
13
```

And the binary file reads as follows:
[image: dat file text]

I am trying to parse the dat file into an array so I can label each data type with the appropriate name such as

```
Name: Fokker DR 1
Country: Germany
Attack Mode: D
Turn Mode: A
etc.
```

But I am having trouble because, when trying to use StreamReader and split the binary file at every instance of a whitespace, I run into problems due to the fact that the Name (Fokker DR 1) contains multiple spaces that should not be split.

Here is my code for my attempted split:

```
if (file.Contains("plane1"))
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("plane1.dat");
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] data = line.Split(' ');
        bin.ReadBinary("plane1.dat");
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + data[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Country: " + data[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Turn Mode: " + data[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("Attack Mode: " + data[3]);
        Console.WriteLine("Cost: " + data[4]);
        Console.WriteLine("Max Damage: " + data[5]);
    }
}
```

Is there any sort of way to split at every instance of a different data type or is there another way to go about labeling the data in my binary file??

Comment: Read about serialization and use one of it like `XmlSerializer`, `BinaryFormatter`, `SoapFormatter`, `JavascriptSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer`, `DataContractJsonSerializer` etc.... Custom serializer/deserializers should handle many extreme cases...

Comment: It looks like the two strings are separated by an ASCII tab (0x07). After that you'll need to know more about the data, e.g. the integer is four bytes, the double is eight bytes and the two characters are stuffed in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BinaryFormatter` will not  handle that file format. Given the small size and straight forward specs some ustom read logic should do the trick.

If you open your file with a [`BinaryReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.BinaryReader(v=vs.110).aspx) you can decide for your self what to do with the next byte or bytes you're about to read. If the format of the file is not to complex this is easy doable. Based on your specs I created this code to read your file:

```
using(var br = new BinaryReader(
    File.Open(@"c:\tmp\plane.dat", FileMode.Open),
    Encoding.ASCII))
{
    while(br.BaseStream.Position < br.BaseStream.Length)
    {
        var name = br.ReadString();
        var country = br.ReadString();
        var turnmode = br.ReadChar();
        var attackmode = br.ReadChar();
        var cost = br.ReadDouble();
        var maxdamage = br.ReadInt32();

        // you can use above vars what ever you need to do 
        // with them, writing to the console or adding to 
        // a list for example
        // Planes.Add(new Plane {Name = name});
    }
}
```

In my test a file I created matched your binary format. As you didn't show where the next record start you might find that you need to do an extra read, for example with a `ReadByte` but that depends on your actual structure.

Comment: In my method called ReadBinary() where I read each individual data type I just ended up "cheating" and writing string strData2 = input.ReadString(); Console.WriteLine("Country: "+ strData2); I say cheating because I don't think that's what I was meant to do, but it got the job done. Thank you for your answer. I tried implementing your way after the fact and it works too.